# Laravel API Sanctum or Passport

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-api

I want create Laravel API and NextJS app. Separate applications.

But, my back-end will be connect to 3th party API. From this 3th party API i will get a token that will allow me to communicate with this API in the next requests.

Overall:

- My NextJS front
- My Laravel API
- 3th party API (Rest, Oauth2)

The question is:

The way I authenticate points *first* and *second* (my app and api) affects my API's communication *second* point  with the *third* point ?

Can i use Sanctum or Passport in communication beetwen first point /second ?

Answer (score 0):

If your front-end(NextJS) only communicates with (Laravel)API i.e SPA, the Sanctum should do the job. Passport is more suitable if API needs to be consumed(resources needs to be consumed/managed) on behalf of a user that is where OAuth2 comes into picture.

Their doc is pretty straight-forward. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#passport-or-sanctum

Backend communication i.e between your Laravel and 3rd Party APIs will not impact Sanctum. In this case, 3rd Party will issue credentials/token so not related.

Comment: I read somewhere that when i choose Sanctum to manage API communication, I can use Fortify for back-end authentication. I mean the built-in functions/routes for registration, login, password reset. Is it true? Maybe I misunderstood the article and I need to manually create the authentication.

Comment: This is a separate question. Please go through the docs instead of any article, you will get answers sooner. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/fortify#when-should-i-use-fortify. If you don't want to put efforts in complete authentication flow, look at starter kit like Laravel Breeze or Laravel Jetstream. Again, go through their docs. They are simple.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no direct communication from your FE to 3rd party APIs then you can use either Sanctum or Passport in your Laravel API project. As a general practice avoid to call 3rd parties directly from FE and create an API for that in your Laravel API project and call that API from FE.